# Apache writing rewrite rules in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I need some rewrite rules for an .htaccess (Apache2 / Ubuntu), these are the conditions:

- site.com -> www.site.com
- subdomain.site.com -> www.site.com/data.php?a=subdomain
- site.com/sub1 -> www.site.com/data.php?b=sub1
- subdomain.site.com/sub1 -> www.site.com/data.php?a=subdomain&b=sub1
- site.com/sub1/sub2 -> www.site.com/data.php?b=sub1&c=sub2
- subdomain.com/sub1/sub2 -> www.site.com/data.php?a=subdomain&b=sub1&c=sub2

My host has already setup subdomain wildcards.

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  Just look at any basic htaccess examples.

Comment: Time to start reading... http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/ If you have specific issues as you're implementing the rules come back and ask for help.